# Get correct brace grouping from string

Tags: python

I have files with incorrect JSON that I want to start fixing by getting it into properly grouped chunks.

The brace grouping `{{ {} {} } } {{}} {{{}}}` should already be correct

How can I grab all the top-level braces, correctly grouped, as separate strings?

Comment: This might not be as trivial as you think. What exactly are you trying to do? add some example input and your expected output.

Comment: If you're sure that there won't be any non-semantic braces (in strings or comments, for example) and you can install the [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), then you can do it with a recursive regex. Would that be an option?

Comment: It is relatively easy to see whether braces are balanced or not. But without additional rules, I cannot imagine a way to add the missing braces in the proper place. Please elaborate on that and at least show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to install any extra modules simple function will do:

```
def top_level(s):
    depth = 0
    start = -1

    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == '{':
            if depth == 0:
                start = i
            depth += 1
        elif c == '}' and depth:
            depth -= 1
            if depth == 0:
                yield s[start:i+1]

print(list(top_level('{{ {} {} } } {{}} {{{}}}')))
```

Output:

```
['{{ {} {} } }', '{{}}', '{{{}}}']
```

It will skip invalid braces but could be easily modified to report an error when they are spotted.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
In [1]: import regex

In [2]: braces = regex.compile(r"\{(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*\}")

In [3]: braces.findall("{{ {} {} } } {{}} {{{}}}")
Out[3]: ['{{ {} {} } }', '{{}}', '{{{}}}']
```

Answer (score 1):

`pyparsing` can be really helpful here.  It will handle pathological cases where you have braces inside strings, etc.  It might be a little tricky to do all of this work yourself, *but* fortunately, somebody (the author of the library) has already done the [hard stuff for us...](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/jsonParser.py).  I'll reproduce the code here to prevent link-rot:

```
# jsonParser.py
#
# Implementation of a simple JSON parser, returning a hierarchical
# ParseResults object support both list- and dict-style data access.
#
# Copyright 2006, by Paul McGuire
#
# Updated 8 Jan 2007 - fixed dict grouping bug, and made elements and
#   members optional in array and object collections
#
json_bnf = """
object
    { members }
    {}
members
    string : value
    members , string : value
array
    [ elements ]
    []
elements
    value
    elements , value
value
    string
    number
    object
    array
    true
    false
    null
"""
from pyparsing import *

TRUE = Keyword("true").setParseAction( replaceWith(True) )
FALSE = Keyword("false").setParseAction( replaceWith(False) )
NULL = Keyword("null").setParseAction( replaceWith(None) )

jsonString = dblQuotedString.setParseAction( removeQuotes )
jsonNumber = Combine( Optional('-') + ( '0' | Word('123456789',nums) ) +
                    Optional( '.' + Word(nums) ) +
                    Optional( Word('eE',exact=1) + Word(nums+'+-',nums) ) )

jsonObject = Forward()
jsonValue = Forward()
jsonElements = delimitedList( jsonValue )
jsonArray = Group(Suppress('[') + Optional(jsonElements) + Suppress(']') )
jsonValue << ( jsonString | jsonNumber | Group(jsonObject)  | jsonArray | TRUE | FALSE | NULL )
memberDef = Group( jsonString + Suppress(':') + jsonValue )
jsonMembers = delimitedList( memberDef )
jsonObject << Dict( Suppress('{') + Optional(jsonMembers) + Suppress('}') )

jsonComment = cppStyleComment
jsonObject.ignore( jsonComment )

def convertNumbers(s,l,toks):
    n = toks[0]
    try:
        return int(n)
    except ValueError, ve:
        return float(n)

jsonNumber.setParseAction( convertNumbers )
```

Phew!  That's a lot ... Now how do we use it?  The general strategy here will be to scan the string for matches and then slice those matches out of the original string.  Each scan result is a tuple of the form `(lex-tokens, start_index, stop_index)`.  For our use, we don't care about the lex-tokens, just the start and stop.  We could do:  `string[result[1], result[2]]` and it would work.  We can also do `string[slice(*result[1:])]` -- Take your pick.

```
results = jsonObject.scanString(testdata)
for result in results:
    print '*' * 80
    print testdata[slice(*result[1:])]
```